# EF 6.0 Cannot retrieve navigation property (Collection) using a Bounded (focused) context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, bounded-contexts

I have started breaking up my "uber" context into smaller focused ones. In a simple scenario, I have `Student` and `Lectures` POCOS and my `EntityTypeConfiguration` defines a many to many relationship between the two in a new table called `StudentsAndLectures`.

These tables are part of a relationship network of tables defined in my uber context. However, I'd like to manage students and their lectures in a more targeted fashion with a focused context.

My POCO classes below.

```
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        Lecture = new List<Lecture>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Lecture> Lectures { get; set; }
}

public class Lecture
{
    public Lecture()
    {
        Students = new List<Student>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, My entity type mappers.

```
public class StudentMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
{
    public StudentMapper()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        HasMany(x => x.Lectures)
            .WithMany(x => x.Students)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("LectureId");
                m.MapRightKey("StudentId");
                m.ToTable("StudentsAndLectures");
            });
        Property(x => x.Name);
    }
}

public class LectureMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<Lecture>
{
    public LectureMapper()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        HasMany(x => x.Students)
            .WithMany(x => x.Lectures)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("LectureId");
                m.MapRightKey("StudentId");
                m.ToTable("StudentsAndLectures");
            });
        Property(x => x.Name);
    }
}
```

Also, My Focused context contains DbSets for only the Students and Lectures.

My problem, If I query for a specific student like below, using my focused context, my Navigation property for .Lectures returns empty. However if I use the full(uber) context that created the db my navigation property gets lazy loaded or eager loaded as i wish. Anyone know why this could be?

```
using(FocusedStudentContext db = new FocusedStudentContext())
{
     var student = db.Students.Include(s => s.Lectures)
                     .FirstOrDefault(s => s.StudentID == 1234);
     // Inspecting student here for the Lectures navigation property
     // collection has 0 elements.
}
```

After further testing and experimenting I found that if I included One particular (none others) additional `DbSet` that exists in my model and it's related `ModelBuilder` configurations then all works fine. The `DbSet` is for an entity, `Registration`, and it's one that has a navigation property to `Student` with a `HasRequired (x => x.Student)`. Another twist is, if i leave the `ModelBuilder` configurations for the `Registration` entity, but remove the `DbSet<Registration>` from my focused context, then my navigation property for `Lectures` stops getting added again. (The collection has 0 elements).

My confusion, how can adding a `DbSet` to my Focused context affect the way my navigation properties get resolved for tables/entities described above? And how can I resolve this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one many-to-many mapping, not two. But even though you could have two mappings, they should be identical. In your case, they aren't. Both mappings have the same columns in `MapLeftKey` and `MapRightKey`,  but they start at different ends. Only the `LectureMapper` is correct.

Apparenty, the `StudentMapper` takes precedence, which I think is determined by the order in which mappings are added to the configuration. The effect is that EF is looking for `Lecture`s by the `StudentId` value in the junction table: very wrong. I can't really explain the effect of including the other mappings and entities that you describe. I just assume that under different circumstances makes EF takes the other mapping first.

But it's just too easy to get `MapLeftKey` and `MapRightKey` wrong. I try to keep them apart by picturing it:

```
Lecture            HasMany    Student
Left: LectureId               Right: StudentId
```

The MSDN description isn't too helpful, e.g. [`MapLeftKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.manytomanyassociationmappingconfiguration.mapleftkey%28v=vs.113%29.aspx):

> Configures the name of the column(s) for the left foreign key. The left foreign key points to the parent entity of the navigation property specified in the HasMany call

The navigation property specified in the HasMany call is `Students`, the parent (or owner) of the property is `Lecture`, which is identitfied by `LectureId`... I go for the visualization.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE I guess I resolved this but not really. I found that if I remove the explicit mapping on the Student and Lectures many to many table and let EF do it that things work fine now.

HasMany(x => x.Students).WithMany(x => x.Lectures);